# query string undefined value in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

trying to access title from url which coming undefined value

```
<form action="/payment" method="post">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">₹ 4500</button>
</form>

app.post('/payment', auth, async(req,res) => {
try {
    const title = req.query.title;
    console.log(title);
    // const userEmail = req.user.email;
    // const getUser = await Payment.insertOne({ email : userEmail, course_Title: },
}
catch(e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
}
})
```

Comment: You use body key not use query.

Answer (score -1):

For query string parameter in express you can use
**req.query.title** to get query parameter and the url should be like
**http://localhost:3000/?title=Payments**